# Acessing rows and columns in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has its keys as tuples and values assigned to these keys.

I want to perform a set of actions based on the keys positions.

Here is my code that I have written so far.

Dictionary:

```
p={(0, 1): 2, (1, 2): 6, (0, 0): 1, (2, 0): 7, (1, 0): 4, (2, 2): 9, (1, 1): 5, (2, 1): 8, (0, 2): 3}
```

Desired output is:

I want the values of individual rows as shown below.

```
q=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

I wrote this code that can do this trick for columns:

```
r=[[p[(x,y)] for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
```

for which the output looks like this:

```
r=[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

I know how to do this with the following set of code:

```
z=[]
for i in range(3):
    z.append([p[i,j] for j in range(3)])
```

Which gives me:

```
z=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

My question is, can I do that operation in just one list comprehension?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you flip `x` and `y` in your code for `r`, it seems to output the way you desire. For example,

```
r=[[p[(x,y)] for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
```

results in

> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured that out. I wrote so much code and got lost in it. I had written it but did not know where I had written it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had tried to do several things in the code. I had written it but did not realize that and went on trying different combinations with code.

Here is the answer:

```
z=[[p[(i,j)] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
```

Thanks!